# Java - SmartString and StringBuilder giving OutofBoundsException

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I'm working on a program that supports inserting into a string, deleting a substring from a string, and an undo method. My professor provided the driver, which shouldn't be changed. I've written my own relevant SmartString and UndoMethod classes (there's also ADT and Test classes, but don't worry about those). But whenever I try to insert a string, I keep getting an IndexOutofBoundsException. I've accounted for the offset in StringBuilder, but I still can't quite get my code to work. The output that I got is below as well. Here is the SmartString class:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class SmartString implements SmartStringADT{

StringBuilder stringBuild = new StringBuilder();
Stack<UndoMethod> undoStack = new Stack<>();
private String newString;
boolean undo = false;

public SmartString(){
    newString = "";
}

public SmartString(String newString){
    StringBuilder stringBuild = new StringBuilder(newString);
}

public void insert(int pos, String sstring) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    stringBuild.insert(pos+1, sstring);
    if(!undo){
        undoStack.push(new UndoMethod(sstring, sstring.length(), pos+1, 2));
    }

}

public void delete(int pos, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    stringBuild.delete(pos, (pos+count));
    if(!undo){
        undoStack.push(new UndoMethod(stringBuild.substring(pos, pos+count), count, pos-1,1));
    }
}

public void undo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    UndoMethod temp = undoStack.pop();
    undo = true;
    if(temp.getAction() == 1){
        insert(temp.getPos(), temp.getString());
    }
    if(temp.getAction() == 2){
        delete(temp.getPos(), temp.getCount());
    }
    undo = false;


}

}
```

My UndoMethod class:

```
public class UndoMethod {

private String ssString;
int count;
int pos;
int action;

public UndoMethod(){
    ssString = "";
    count = 0;
    pos = 0;
    action = 0;
}

public UndoMethod(String SSString, int Count, int Position, int Action){
    ssString = SSString;
    count = Count;
    pos = Position;
    action = Action;
}

public String getString(){
    return ssString;
}

public void setString(String SSString){
    ssString = SSString;
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public int getPos() {
    return pos;
}

public void setPos(int pos) {
    this.pos = pos;
}

public int getAction() {
    return action;
}

public void setAction(int action) {
    this.action = action;
}


}
```

My output:

> Enter an action
>
> 1
>
> Enter the position (begin counting at 0) of the letter after which to insert
>
> 19
>
> Enter the string to insert
>
> I am doing great!
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String >index out of range: 20
>
> > at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.insert(AbstractStringBuilder.java:1005)
> >
> > at java.lang.StringBuilder.insert(StringBuilder.java:291)
> >
> > at SmartString.insert(SmartString.java:20)
> >
> > at SmartStringDriver.main(SmartStringDriver.java:38)

And for reference, the driver class, which should be good:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Declare variables and objects
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int action = 1, start = 0, count = 0;
    String menu = "\n(1) insert\n(2) delete\n(3) Undo\n(4) Quit";
    SmartString str;
    String insertS = "";


    System.out.println("Enter your initial Smart String:");
    str = new SmartString(scan.nextLine());
    try{
      do{
            //Prompt for an action - Insert, Delete, Undo, Quit
            System.out.println("Your smart string is: \n\t" + str + " \n\t(indexing from 0 to " + (str.toString().length()-1) + " - length of " + str.toString().length() + ")");
            System.out.println(menu);
            System.out.println("Enter an action");

            action = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();

            //Determine which action and prompt for necessary input
            switch (action) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter the position (begin counting at 0) of the letter after which to insert " + insertS);
                start = scan.nextInt();
                scan.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter the string to insert");
                insertS = scan.nextLine();

                //Invoke SmartString insert method
                str.insert(start, insertS);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Enter the position (begin counting at 0) of the first letter to delete");
                start = scan.nextInt();             

                System.out.println("Enter the number of letters to delete (count)");
                count = scan.nextInt();

                //Invoke SmartString delete method
                str.delete(start, count);
                break;

            case 3:
                //Invoke SmartString undo method
                str.undo();             
                break;
            }

      }while (action != 4);
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Entry must be numeric!");
    }
    System.out.println("\n Your final Smart String is " + str);

}

}
```

EDIT: Also, here's the SmartStringADT:

```
public interface SmartStringADT {
public void insert(int pos, String sstring);
public void delete(int pos, int count);
public void undo();
public String toString();
}
```

Comment: What is this `SmartStringADT` interface? More importantly, what debugging have you done as this question suggests that the solution is to be found by doing careful debugging, not by asking here?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't fast enough -- hit enter as I was formatting and finishing the post. Adding the output to the code. To answer your question, I've tried changing my offset position, as the error comes from that line. But no matter what I change it to, I get the exception.

Comment: What unclear about that exception? Your StringBuilder isn't long enough for inserting something at that index.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I've tried it with every possible index. Every index is out of bounds, which doesn't make a lot of sense. Also, we're told in the driver to insert "at the position of the letter" after which we want to insert, but if I'm remembering correctly, StringBuilder adds at the offset, so I did pos+1. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I think you need to check `length()` on the builder before calling `insert()`, and if it’s not large enough, call `setLength(pos + sstring.length())`.  At minimum, I think the length has to be `pos + 1` to not throw.  Check the javadocs for the insert method, and see what the exception conditions are.  The documentation should describe any preconditions that you might be violating.

Comment: Your StringBuilder is ___always___ empty, thus every index is invalid.

Comment: Right, you can always `append`, but you can only `insert` at position before the end of the current content.  No content => no insert.  `setLength` should fill in any newly created space with null terminators.

Comment: @Tom: Could you explain a little more? I thought that by setting it in the constructor to the new SmartString being created in the driver, it would set that string to StringBuilder. Did that not happen?

Comment: @MikeStrobel Just to be clear, my comment was for OP ;P.

Comment: No you constructor is wrong: [Why does Java throw NullPointerException here?](//stackoverflow.com/q/30567802)

Comment: I suggest to add a breakpoint on the insert method, you'll easily find the error.